# Reference Books for Hindu/Indian Mythology, Culture & Philosophy?

Tags: philosophy, culture, book-recommendation

What concise classical references do we have in English of Hindu/Indian mythology, religion and philosophy subjects especially from the colonial period by non-Indian indologists? An objective narrative from a non-indian viewpoint may be interesting in this changing world. The following is one such but is not really sufficient on Indian philosophy.

[Dictionary of Hindu Mythology and Religion](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=PwsYAAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=dhara%20sacrifiA%20Classical%20Dictionary%20of%20Hindu%20Mythology%20and%20Religion,%20Geography,%20History%20...ce%20flow%20water&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjK7ZCVpNvTAhWIr48KHbGmACoQ6AEINDAD#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: You should only post a question if you're actually asking a question.  It is possible to use Hinduism.SE to share some knowledge you have, but the way to do that is post a question and then post an answer to your own question.  But regardless, the question should be in the form of an actual question.

Comment: Included a question as suggested.

Comment: First we should read the indian viewpoint lol... since they were the original authors. Due to translation and western ideologies, true purport of author is lost in many english books.

Comment: Bertrand Russell well known intellectual said that civilizations perish when they do not come in contact with other civilizations. At the least others' viewpoint is some guarantee..

Comment: Any work that takes a narrative standpoint bring with them biases that are tacit to the author of the exposition. Given this ground reality, the requirement of non-Indian viewpoint needs leveling with the requirement of non-colonial viewpoint (i.e., exclusion of works arising with connections to colonial forces) to be in some measure objective. Is this intent implicit from your end? If it is so, stating this explicitly in the question will help focus the community's search for an answer.